# Why does webpack create strange font files?

Tags: webpack

Everytime I run webpack it seems to output a new set of font files. They're always named for a long string of random characters like a hash. For example,

76a4f23cb373829c9382900d9dfs9830sdf.svg

There are .eot, .woff, .woff2 etc files.

The problem is the files accumulate in github everytime we generate a new package. Is there some way to force webpack to use specific names for these files?

Comment: You might want to consider `.gitignore`-ing your build files.

Comment: But those files are necessary. Not including them results in missing fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It is a hash.

By default the filename resulting from loading the font file with [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) is the MD5 hash of the file's contents with the original extension of the required resource.

If you want, you can configure a custom filename template for your file using the query parameter `name`. You can specify to keep the same path, name and extension using the following template in your fonts loader rule:

```
'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
```

For example, if you want to apply this template to the `svg` files:

```
loader: [
  { test: /.svg$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]' }
]
```

Modify the `test` field accordingly to match all your fonts.